# Function discontinuous on $(0,1)$ continuous everywhere else

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Find a function continuous everywhere but $(0,1)$.

Attempt:

Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases} -x+1,& \quad x<0\\1, & \quad x \in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1] \\ 0, & \quad x \in \mathbb{Q^c}\cap [0,1] \\x,& \quad x>1  \end{cases}$$

Is this function okay, satisfying the desired property? The solution gave a different answer.

Comment: Function isn't continuous at 0 or 1.

Comment: Function isn't continuous at 0 **and** 1.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0,& \quad x<0\\x(x-1), & \quad x \in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1] \\ 0, & \quad x \in \mathbb{Q^c}\cap [0,1] \\0,& \quad x>1  \end{cases}$$

Comment: How do you know it is continuous at 0 and at 1?

Comment: Taking limit from right and left gives function value at point.